# How to pass data to nth view controller on the UINavigationController stack?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, delegates, protocols

There are 2 apps A & B.

App A has a url to open App B.

Soon as App B opens, it has to load 5 view controllers onto the navigation stack which is done by the following code:

```
let LandingVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LandingVC") as! LandingVC
let Dashboard = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Dashboard") as! Dashboard
let PlayerVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlayerVC") as! PlayerVC
let PlayerDetailVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlayerDetailVC") as! PlayerDetailVC
let ScoreReportVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ScoreReportVC") as! ScoreReportVC
let viewControllersList = [LandingVC, Dashboard, PlayerVC, PlayerDetailVC, ScoreReportVC]
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllersList, animated: false)
```

From `ScoreReportVC` I need to be able to set variables on previous `ViewController`s so that the user can navigate to previous screens even though they fired the application from another application.

Here is what I have tried: defined a protocol in previous view controllers that are behind `ScoreReportVC` that are on the stack and inside `ScoreReportVC` like so:

```
for viewcontroller in self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
if viewcontroller is PlayerDetailVC {
    PlayerDetailVC.delegate = self
}
if viewcontroller is PlayerVC {
    PlayerVC = self
}
if viewcontroller is Dashboard {
    Dashboard.delegate = self
}
if viewcontroller is LandingVC {
    LandingVC.delegate = self
}
}
```

But the delegates are not getting called. Any help how to correctly pass data to all the `ViewController`s on the stack would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you pop from ScoreReportVC ?

Comment: I’m unable to tell the issue because debugger stops at a background thread and won’t show the previous screen.

Comment: Maybe the instances of your UIViewControllers are being removed from the memory sooner than you expected it to be, this could be the reason why the delegate methods are not being called.

Comment: Also, have you tried setting the delegate outside the loop? Just curious.

Comment: Tried setting it outside the loop, results are same. Trying a backtrack and able to see all the view controllers still existing on the navigation stack.

Comment: ok, I kinda don't like your idea, so i offer using coordinator pattern or simply put you'll create specific class that will hold all data needed by all controllers and the controllers will get data from it

Comment: Each class will make their own network calls so I’m not sure if coordinator pattern is ideal here. Can my solution be tweaked somehow to accommodate the data flow?

Answer (score 0):

For relatable classes we use Delegations. But the classes which are not relatable , for those, we use Notifications. In your case Notifications will be needed for implementation and to pass data from one VC to another VC.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to create/set the variables when the controllers are created.

Comment: There is a network call happening on the nth `ViewController` but they are added to the stack a lot earlier than the network call. So I don't think that is viable.

Comment: Then all of your controllers should adopt a common protocol which updates the variable using a generic parameter.

Comment: Protocol is what I have implemented. None of the protocols are working. What difference will it make if I generalize it all into one protocol?

Comment: With protocol adopted you don't need to use delegate you can invoke those methods of respective controller directly as viewcontroller.someMethod()